# JMeter Assertion Results

Tags: groovy, jmeter, assertions, jsr223

I am running JSR223 Assertion where I compare expected response to actual response using groovy. If they are not equal, assertion fails. 
Here is the code

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper();
boolean set_assertion = true;

def expected_response = slurper.parseText("<JSON response goes here>");
def actual_response = slurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());

if (expected_response != actual_response)
{
    set_assertion = false;
    log.error("expected_response != actual_response");
    assert set_assertion == true;
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);  
}
```

Now, assertion does fail. But I think it fails because I get internal error in the logs.
Here is my Assertion result. 
[Assertion Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwL1N.png)
Here is the logs

```
ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Error processing Assertion  Assertion failed: 

assert set_assertion == true
       |             |
       false         false

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.assertFailed(InvokerHelper.java:402)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.assertFailed(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:650)
    at Script48.run(Script48.groovy:16)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:153)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:206)
    at org.apache.jmeter.assertions.JSR223Assertion.getResult(JSR223Assertion.java:47)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processAssertion(JMeterThread.java:755)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.checkAssertions(JMeterThread.java:746)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:410)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:241)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Ideally I should not have errors, and my assertion should fail and should have the following results 'Assertion error:false' and 'Assertion failure:true'.

Could you please help me understand where I am making a mistake. My most concern is the error in the logs. Thank you!

Comment: You want to do the assert, but not have it throw the error? Don't think I understand... Just don't do the assert line

Comment: @tim_yates Shouldn't it catch the error? I have a Response Assertion that fails, but doesn't give me an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what's happening:

You're using Groovy "assert". As below comparison is false:

> expected_response != actual_response

You end up failing on:

> assert set_assertion == true;

This throws org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.powerassert.PowerAssertionError which is a subclass or java.lang.Error which is trapped here:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterThread.java#L771

So JMeter executes this code which is what you get:

> ```
>         assertionResult = new AssertionResult("Assertion failed! See log file.");
>         assertionResult.setError(true);
>         assertionResult.setFailureMessage(e.toString());
> ```

This seems fine to me, but why use Groovy assert here ? it will be much more efficient to just do this:

```
 if ( expected_response != actual_response )
 {
      log.error("expected_response != actual_response");
      AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
      AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("expected_response != actual_response");
 }
```

You can learn more on assertions reading this [blog](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/best-practice-using-jmeter-assertions/).